# toolbar is not hiding automatically need to push manually to hide while scrolling in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout, android-coordinatorlayout

My app contains a fragment with toolbar , linear layout and Tabllayout. I have enabled the scrollflags to the toolbar. Now when i try scrolling in the recyclerview in the tablayout the toolbar is not hinding.  When i Push the tablayout manually it started moving and able to hide or show. Below are the layouts which I am using. What is wrong here.

Main layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">



<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:id="@+id/app">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/textcolor"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/backblack" />


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layloc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:visibility="gone">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/locationname"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/location"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/location"
            android:drawablePadding="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/cblack"
            android:text="fetching current location"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium.Inverse"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/change"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Change"
            android:drawablePadding="3dp"
            android:textColor="@color/cblack"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"/>

    </LinearLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layloc"
    android:background="@color/textcolor"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/black"
    app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
    app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Fragment layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/textcolor"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:id="@+id/mainexplore">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/lists"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1px"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/emptyElement"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="@string/nofoodfound"
    android:textColor="@color/button"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have tried with the different scroll flags but the problem is same. I have seen examples and some issues similar to this in the SO but none of them answers my query. The toolbar can be able to hide but need to push manually. What is the wrong with the layouts. What is missing in this layouts.

Comment: what's theme of application or activity?

Comment: @KaranMer - Please check my layout it is present already.

Comment: I just did it in code. Monitor scroll change. Then show or hide it. If scrolling down, I hide it, if scrolling up I show it. Pretty simple to do in code on scroll change. Probably save yourself a bunch of time

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove button view from appBarLayout. Check mine.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="@color/textcolor"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/back"
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="start"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/backblack" />

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: you want to hide toolbar when you scroll up in recyclerview right ?

Comment: Yes. For the layout in the question.